# MySQL query select and compute value

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
SELECT 
if('1000'>plan_limit_max,'1000'-plan_limit_max,0) as 'Overage',
if(`per_hour_cost`='0', `per_period_cost`+'10'*`Overage`, per_hour_cost*720) AS 'Total'

FROM `service_price`

order by Total asc
;
```

There is an error with `Overage` at line 3

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Overage' in 'field list'
```

Is there a way to do what I want with one query?
I want to order results by total price, but to calculate it I have to calculate the usage exceeds the limit.

I know there should be other ways to do it, use more than one queries, create views, etc..
I just wonder if there is a simpler query for this.

Comment: Can you post the error as well?

Comment: Why are you single-quoting what look like numeric constants (e.g., `'1000'`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute `Overage` once, in a subquery:

```
SELECT Overage,
       IF(per_hour_cost = 0, per_period_cost + 10 * Overage, per_hour_cost * 720)
         AS Total
  FROM (SELECT IF(1000 > plan_limit_max, 1000 - plan_limit_max, 0) AS Overage,
               service_price.*
          FROM service_price) d;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Overage** is not defined as part of the query, only as the column header in the result.   You cannot reference that column as it does not yet exist...   You've got to use something like the SQL below:

```
SELECT 
if('1000'>plan_limit_max,'1000'-plan_limit_max,0) as 'Overage',
if(`per_hour_cost`='0', `per_period_cost`+'10'*if('1000'>plan_limit_max,'1000'-             plan_limit_max,0), 
per_hour_cost*720) AS 'Total'

FROM `service_price`

order by Total asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error putting " `` " in OVERAGE. You must use '  ' in OVERAGE.

```
SELECT 
if('1000'>plan_limit_max,'1000'-plan_limit_max,0) as 'Overage',
if(`per_hour_cost`='0', `per_period_cost`+'10'* 'Overage', per_hour_cost*720) AS 'Total'

FROM `service_price`

order by Total asc
;
```

Comment: No, that will force string interpretation of the token `Overage`.  MySQL will summarily truncate that to a zero and will issue a warning something like:  `Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Overage'`